# Naming brew command to special character

Tags: ruby, homebrew

How can I set up a script to PATH with a different name than the repo using brew. For example, let's say I have

**percent.rb**

```rb
    puts to_f(ARGV[0]) * to_i(ARGV[1])
```

in a repo called `homebrew-percent`.

How can I turn this script into the command `%` on brew install where it can later be ran as `% 99 1000` in bash and get 990

**Edit:** I'd like to be clear that percent is an *example*, not my actual project.

Comment: what does repo have to do with with your code? how is any of this relevant to homebrew?

Comment: @lacostenycoder because I'd like to push this project to Homebrew where I can run `%` (and not `percent`) in bash and get that result.

Comment: There is still nothing specific to homebrew here. Is this for your use only?  But why can't you just use `alias %='percent'` ?

Comment: also in ruby `2 * 2 == 4` that is multiplication not percentage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you pushed your code to `https://github.com/Jack/homebrew-percent` and tagged it `0.1.0`, you can create a formula like so:

```
# percent.rb
class Percent < Formula
  homepage "https://github.com/Jack/homebrew-percent"
  url "https://github.com/Jack/homebrew-percent/archive/0.1.0.tar.gz"

  def install
    bin.install "percent.rb" => "%"
  end
end
```

Note: I wrote a very minimalist formula here; you may want to check Homebrew’s docs regarding [how write a formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Formula-Cookbook.md) and [host it in your own repo](https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap).

Then, run `brew install ./percent.rb`. You now have a `%` executable in your path.
**However** it *won’t* work if you use Bash, as `%` is already recognized as a command (equivalent to `fg`).

You may want to use a different alias, such as e.g. `p`. You can also install it as `percent` then add an alias in your `~/.bash_profile` or equivalent startup file.